# Error adding patches to patchset

Tags: netlogo

**I can't understand the problem with the code:**

```
 ask patches with [....][set patches-in-box (patch-set patches-in-box self)]
```

**It gives me an error**

PATCH-SET expected input to be a patch agentset or patch but got the number 0 instead.
error while patch 15 4 running PATCH-SET

I am using self incorrectly here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean `self` here, not `myself`.

`self` refers to this agent. `myself` refers to some other agent, the agent that asked this agent to do what it is currently doing.

```
observer> crt 2
observer> ask turtle 0 [ ask turtle 1 [ print self print myself ] ]
(turtle 1)
(turtle 0)
```

But that can't explain the error that you're getting, which states that one of the inputs you're giving to `patch-set` is the number 0. Neither `self` nor `myself` can ever be a number, so the culprit must be `patches-in-box`.

Apparently before beginning you've forgotten to initialize `patches-in-box` to the empty set, like this:

```
set patches-in-box no-patches
```

Comment: Yep you are right that was silly error on my part though the error still persists: PATCH-SET expected input to be a patch agentset or patch but got the number 0 instead. I don't understand it should clearly return a patch

Comment: Answer augmented to cover this.